# mounting local network folder in Ubuntu

Tags: terminal, mount, fstab

I add a folder in /etc/fstab:

```
//172.30.12.37/test/ /home/my/test cifs user=afs,pass=123456,auto,exec,umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Now test link can be seen in nautilus sidebar. But when I click on this icon, an error will be displayed:

```
mount: only root can mount //172.30.12.37/test/ on /home/my/test
```

How I can mount this folder from terminal with root user?

Comment: have you tried `sudo mount -a`

Comment: sudo mount ssh://172.30.12.37/afs/ /home/my/afs37/‍‍ And result: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ssh://172.30.12.37/afs

Comment: why are you trying via ssh ? in post you have mention cifs.

Comment: mount 172.30.12.37/test /home/my/afs37/ >>> result >>> mount: special device 172.30.12.37/test does not exist

Comment: @chalist Shouldn't it be `sudo mount -t cifs //172.30.12.37/test /home/my/afs37/`?

Comment: @Karlson No dude.

Comment: If it is in fstab (and fstab is set up correctly), root should be able to run `mount /home/my/test` to mount it... (as root, use sudo or su to root (if you set up a password for root))

Comment: @GertvandenBerg I don't know where is problem, but I use ssh to fix my to-do list now.

Comment: Start by removing all the fstab options (add just a `defaults`) If it then work, add them back gradually... (If the server is not running Windows, the Unix extensions on CIFS allows permissions to actually work over CIFS...) Also, remove the trailing slash after the share name... Your fstab entry is equivalent to this manual mount command `mount -t cifs -o user=afs,pass=123456,auto,exec,umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //172.30.12.37/test/ /home/my/test`... Still think the slash might cause your issues...

Comment: @chalist I'd look into what @gert-van-den-berg said, but otherwise, I'm think it may be impossible to do this in `fstab`. you may have to muck around with FUSE (although this works in `fstab`, not sure how they interact) or e.g. `gvfs`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `user` option in your **opts** at `/etc/fstab`.

From `man 8 mount`:

> `user`   Allow  an  ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the mounting user is written to mtab so that he can unmount the filesystem again.  This option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in
>                 the option line user,exec,dev,suid).

Answer (score 0):

You have more options:

1. replace user `asf` and its pass with root and root password, if you have any. Since you are on Ubuntu, it's not trivial.
2. add rights to user "asf", allow him to mount as root. Create one file in /etc/sudoers.d/ as root, named i.e. `asf-mount`, and with the following one line content:

   ```
   asf ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
   ```

Also change the access rights of this file to read-only: `sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/asf-mount`, and logout and login again with user `asf`.

Comment: Don't work dude